# Ng-disabled not reacting on changes in value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

I'm trying to disable submit button while some async call is in progress, but it looks like `ng-disabled` isn't watching for value change. Here is the code sample:

Markup:

```
<button ng-show="!resetSuccess" class="form-input login-button" ng-disabled="changeFormError || changeFormProgress", ng-click="resetPassword(changeForm)">Send Email</button>
```

JS:

```
scope.resetPassword = function (form) {
    if (form.$valid) {
        scope.changeFormProgress = true; // value is changed, but ng-disable doesn't react on it
        // scope.$digest(); produces an error
        someAsyncCallReturningPromise.then(function () {
            scope.changeFormProgress = false;
            scope.changeForm.$setPristine();
        }, function (err) {
            scope.changeFormProgress = false;
            scope.changeFormError = true; // changeFormError works ok, ng-disabled watches it
        }); 
    scope.changeFormError = true;
};
```

It looks like $digest isn't called after `scope.changeFormProgress = true;` for some reason, but if I try to add it manually with `scope.$digest();`, I got error `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`. So, is there a way to make ng-disabled watch for value change in this situation?

Comment: try setting read-only

Comment: @TNC sorry, looks like `ng-readonly="changeFormProgress"` doesn't work too

Comment: Hmm I don't see why this shouldn't work. Could you set up a Plunker for this?

Comment: if I add <div>ng-bind="changeFormProgress")</div> to markup, I can't see changes there too, it looks like problem is that $digest isn't called when value changes

Comment: @Aron sure, I'll try to set up Plunker

Answer (score 0):

You must change `scope` to `$scope`

Comment: Depending on how `$scope` is injected, it may not be necessary. Eg when using the array syntax you can do `['$scope', function(scope){}]`